# Find second argument from first argument in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following problem: let L be a list ( (i,j), w_i,j ) for i and j between 1 and N. Suppose we know the couple (i,j) (for example : (5,8)), is there a way to find w_5,8 only from the list L?
NB: my code is a priori better if I use the liste L instead of a matrix w[i][j], since it is mostly empty, so I would rather not use such a matrix.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to store and lookup values of a (sparse) matrix, which I assume is the goal here.

### Option 1

Do not attempt to optimize to early. Depending on what kind of computations you want to perform on the matrix you may be best advised to simply use a [numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.array-creation.html) and do not worry about sparseness.

If your matrix is really large and indeed sparse you can use the specialised sparse matrix implementations of [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

### Option 2

You already have the list `L` in the format you described and you do not want to use any of the numeric packages mentioned above. Then you can convert `L` into a dictionary for easy value lookup:

```
# example list
L = [((1,2), 456.5), ((5,4), 33.5)]

# convert to dictionary
D = dict(L)
# lookup
v = D[(1,2)] # v is now 456.5
# missing value
v = D[(3,3)] # throws KeyNotFound exception

# convert to dictionary with default value for missing keys
from collections import defaultdict
D = defaultdict(int, L)
# lookup
v = D[(1,2)] # v is now 456.5
# missing value
v = D[(3,3)] # v is now 0
```